# How to properly move server to new hardware?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, migration

I run a small server on my home network that has Windows Server 2008 R2 installed. If I wanted to move this windows installation to a completely new PC with better specs, what's the easiest way to do this? Can I simply swap the primary drive to the new machine? I'd hope that Windows would boot up and recognize the new hardware and install new drivers for everything.

I run a domain controller, DNS server, and I setup VPN on my server. I want all of these settings to be retained.

Comment: you can do what you suggest, although I haven't tried with a server and licensing restraints may come into play. but it sure isn't the "proper" way. @Jason has the right idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way or the easy way?

The proper way is to do a fresh install of Windows Server on your new device, join it to the domain, promote it to DC, make it a GC, redirect DNS to it, then demote and remove the old server.

If you want the easy way, get a 2 week IT copy of [ShadowProtect](http://www.storagecraft.com/shadow_protect_IT_edition.php). Use that to image the server to new hardware.

Comment: I guess I meant the "easy way", but also the "easy free way". Also, what is a GC? I don't really know much about servers.

Comment: GC is a global catalog. See this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728188(WS.10).aspx